# Using multiple mongodb databases and having dynamic calls based on url

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am not sure if should i create multiple databases or not. But I think multiple db would create better data.
So I want to create a app, where users can post the link for a particular concept and other users can upvote/downvote it.
like
/react/useState
/javascript/optionalChaning

so here users can post a link(blog, article) for useState concept.
I want, if I hit /react/useState then it should go in react database and go in useState collection and show me all the documents available. It can be /react/useRef meaning → react database and useRef collection.

same for /javascript/optionalChaning → javascript database and optionalChaining collection and return all documents inside it.

How can I achieve this using multiple databases

```
/[database]/[collection]/[documented]
/react/useState
/react/useRef/3246276782634
```

go to that particular db then go into that particular collection?

mongodb forum url - https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/using-multiple-db-in-one-project/211383?u=akshay_shinde

I am totally clueless, going with only one database will solve it, but i want to scale it for all the topics/languages/frameworks. So having seperate db will might solve it.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use multiple databases. Why do you think it could be better?

Comment: so I feel for react there are multiple topics means multiple links for the same topic. The same will be for javascript, python, flutter and so on. So rather than storing all data at one place I am thinking to store the respective data in respective database of that language.

Comment: One driver to have multiple databases is usually user and access management. Or other constraints, e.g. on sharded cluster you can define the primary shard only on database level. In your use-case it does not make much difference, I would say.